# admin grid in custom module not showing up

Tags: magento-1.9

I have seen this question in so many threads but nothing helped me to solve my issue. Admin grid not showing up, I have used the below code to display grid, but nothing working.

config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Spritz_RequestQuotation>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Spritz_RequestQuotation>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <spritz_requestquotation>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Spritz_RequestQuotation</module>
                <frontName>RequestQuotation</frontName>
            </args>
        </spritz_requestquotation>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <spritz_requestquotation>
                <file>spritz_requestquotation.xml</file>
            </spritz_requestquotation>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <web>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Spritz_RequestQuotation</module>
                <frontName>web</frontName>
            </args>
        </web>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <spritz_requestquotation module="spritz_requestquotation">
            <title>Request Quotations</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="spritz_requestquotation">
                    <title>Quotations</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>web/adminhtml_web</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </spritz_requestquotation>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <spritz_requestquotation>
                        <title>RequestQuotation Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </spritz_requestquotation>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <spritz_requestquotation>
                <file>quotation.xml</file>
            </spritz_requestquotation>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml> 
<global>
    <models>
        <spritz_requestquotation>
            <class>Spritz_RequestQuotation_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>web_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </spritz_requestquotation>
        <web_mysql4>
            <class>Spritz_RequestQuotation_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <spritz_requestquotation>
                    <table>quotations</table>
                </spritz_requestquotation>
            </entities>
        </web_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <web_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Spritz_Quotation</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </web_setup>
        <web_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </web_write>
        <web_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </web_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <spritz_requestquotation>
            <class>Spritz_RequestQuotation_Block</class>
        </spritz_requestquotation>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <spritz_requestquotation>
            <class>Spritz_RequestQuotation_Helper</class>
        </spritz_requestquotation>
    </helpers>
    <template>
        <email>
            <spritzrequestquotation_email_template translate="label" module="spritz_requestquotation">
                <label>Request Quotation Email</label>
                <file>requestquotation_email_template.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </spritzrequestquotation_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/quotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<web_adminhtml_web_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="web/adminhtml_web" name="web" />
    </reference>
</web_adminhtml_web_index>
```

controllers/Adminhtml/WebController.php

```
class Spritz_RequestQuotation_Adminhtml_WebController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action{

protected function _initAction() {  
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('spritz_requestquotation/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

    return $this;
}   

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_title($this->__('Quotation'))->_title($this->__('Manage Quotation'));
    $this->_initAction();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

Block/Adminhtml/Web/Grid.php

```
class Spritz_RequestQuotation_Block_Adminhtml_Web_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->setId('webGrid');
  $this->setDefaultSort('quotation_id');
  $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
  $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
  $collection = Mage::getModel('web/web')->getCollection();
  $this->setCollection($collection);
  return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('quotation_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('web')->__('ID'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'quotation_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('title', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('web')->__('Title'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'title',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('web')->__('Status'),
      'align'     => 'left',
      'width'     => '80px',
      'index'     => 'status',
      'type'      => 'options',
      'options'   => array(
          1 => 'Enabled',
          2 => 'Disabled',
      ),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('web')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('web')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('web')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('web')->__('XML'));

  return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('quotation_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('web');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
         'label'    => Mage::helper('web')->__('Delete'),
         'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
         'confirm'  => Mage::helper('web')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('web/status')->getOptionArray();

    array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('web')->__('Change status'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
         'additional' => array(
                'visibility' => array(
                     'name' => 'status',
                     'type' => 'select',
                     'class' => 'required-entry',
                     'label' => Mage::helper('web')->__('Status'),
                     'values' => $statuses
                 )
         )
    ));
    return $this;
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
  return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}

}
```

I have tried in so many ways nothing worked. Please anyone help me to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: is your custom admin route working ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, Its showing empty page.

Comment: @dependencyHell, Yes its working.

Comment: @dependencyHell, If I echo text in both function, admin side its displaying.

Comment: @dependencyHell, In both function its working.

Comment: @dependencyHell, I have commented the _prepareMassaction() and commented columns except one in  _prepareColumns Still it's showing an empty page.

Comment: @dependencyHell, Iam using my custom table for this module. I havent imported table using module. It will give any problem.

Comment: Check that your layout is loaded adding a debug on this file :
`app/code/core/Mage/Page/Helper/Layout.php`

`$handles = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();`

Comment: @dependencyHell, I have printed text in Grid.php _construct function, Text it's not showing up in admin side.

Comment: I have checked, Its quotation.xml file only, I have called the same file in config.xml between <layout> tags.

Comment: Does the layout file contains the ending </layout> ? Yes, Its having ending tag.

Comment: Also, try `<block type="web/adminhtml_web" name="web" />`
to `<block type="web/adminhtml_web_grid" name="grid" />`

Or just set your controller to : `Spritz_RequestQuotation_Block_Adminhtml_Web` and `Web.php`

Comment: I have changed the block type, Still its showing empty page.

Comment: And you have your custom layout in the $handles var from this file : app/code/core/Mage/Page/Helper/Layout.php `$handles = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87747/discussion-on-question-by-sudhakar-sj-admin-grid-in-custom-module-not-showing-up).

Answer (score 0):

It Seems you are calling an Invalid Block Type, try changing your adminhtml layout

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/quotation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <layout version="0.1.0">
      <web_adminhtml_web_index>
         <reference name="content">
            <block type="spritz_requestquotation/adminhtml_web_grid" name="web" />
        </reference>
      </web_adminhtml_web_index>
    </layout>
```

Also in your **Grid.php** you are calling a helper class **Mage::helper('web')**, but i dont find it in your config.xml file. if the class is not there try replacing it with 
Mage::helper('spritz_requestquotation').

If your model class is set properly you will get the Grid showing up.